# simple alternatives to \hrulefill or \rule{\textwidth}{0.5px}

Tags: rules

I am trying to insert horizontal lines for students to write answers.  If I use `\hrulefill`, it only inserts the horizontal line from the end of text to the right margin.  I want this horizontal line to be on a line by itself.  In order to get a horizontal line appearing on its own I would have to add a single character before the `\hrulefill` which looks horrible.

`\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}` works, except the `\textwidth` gets pushed to the right beyond the right margin when using `\itemize`

I'm looking for a better solution that places a blank line like in the the last last horizontal line, but without the letter "a".

Sorry, I cannot figure out how to include the pdf output for the code below.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] \hrulefill \\\\
    \hrulefill
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1]\\\\
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
    a \hrulefill
    \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

Corrected px to pt, `\itemize` to `\begin{itemize}` followed by `\end{itemize}`

Note:  I'm actually surprised px worked, as well as the `\itemize` by itself.

Comment: `\linewidth` should be compatible with intemize.  BTW, px is not a native LaTeX unit, but `\the\dimexpr 1px\relax` came out to about 1pt.

Comment: Please note that `itemize` is an *environment*, and should be used as `\begin{itemize}` and `\end{itemize}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\answerrule}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \noindent
  \rule{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}%
  \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\answerrule

\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1][1-4]

\answerrule
\answerrule
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

##### Important notes

1. `\itemize` must not be used in the body of the document. Use ***only*** the environment form `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`. The same for ***every*** LaTeX environment.
2. There is actually no `px` unit. Well, there is, but it defaults to be the same as `pt` and has nothing to do with the resolution of the device where the PDF file is viewed.
3. Avoid `\\\\` to get vertical space.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
\item \lipsum[1]
\hrulefill \break \null\hrulefill \break \null\hrulefill
```

Each `\hrulefill\break` runs to the end of line, next line must be started by the "invisible character" `\null`, no by the visible character "a". If such a character isn't here then next `\hrulefill` is canceled by TeX, because it is a glue and glue is "discardable item" from TeX's point of view.